# How to add hover effect to visio drawing in sharepoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint, hover, web-parts, visio

I've created a web part page which contains visio drawing in sharepoint site. Now I want to show shape data when the mouse hover on specific shapes, instead of clicking "Toggle the visibility of shape information pane".

e.g. When mouse hovers at one employee image, more detailed information which is included in "Shape Data" can pop up, showing "Name:XXX, ID:XXX, Age:XXX..."

I've tried to add "Comment" in "shape sheet", but the hover over effect only works in Visio Design Mode. It does not work after I integrated the drawing in sharepoint webpart.

Also, I tried another approach by saving visio drawing as htm webpage. However, the data will not be dynamically updated in that way.

How could I achieve this function? Do I need to use javascript? If so, how could I integrate javascript to the webpage I already created with visio drawing?

Comment: May be [SVG Publish](https://unmanagedvisio.com/svgexport-updated-1-2-10/) extension can helps?

Answer (score 0):

This will walk you through the process.

[Creating an Office Plan ECMAScript Mashup Drawing in Visio 2010 to Display in SharePoint Server 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg243427.aspx)

Comment: try to avoid pasting link answers, explaining it and then pasting a link at the end is better